# Elasticsearch sometimes failing to execute fetch phase

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Currently, all search queries that are passed into ES are truncated to 1000 characters. Regardless, every so often we get this error:

```
[2019-10-08T15:44:08,126][DEBUG][o.e.a.s.TransportSearchAction] [zir05M0] [135539946] Failed to execute fetch phase
org.elasticsearch.transport.RemoteTransportException: [zir05M0][__IP__][__PATH__[__PATH__]]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: This builder doesn't allow terms that are larger than 1,000 characters, got <some really long string of text>
```

I'm a novice when it comes to Elasticsearch and really don't know where to begin in trying to debug this. My only guess is that a `more_like_this` query is using a field that's too long, but I can't confirm that. If anyone has any hints that could get me going down the right track would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you log the query when it throws an exception? Is that possible in your use case?

Comment: I don't believe it is. We have logging set up through BugSnag and I couldn't find any bugs around the time that this one was thrown. I'm not actually 100% sure where this log even came from, it was delegated down to me and I've been rather unlucky in solving it so far.